# Displaying FAA METAR data in a Google Maps bubble

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xsd

I'll preface this with I'm still fairly new to programming and still learning all the tools to make internet magic. I've been trying to figure out how I can take the Schema data from the aviationweather.gov site and display the results in google maps when you click on a marker. I'm pretty sure most of my issue is not knowing the correct language, but any help is greatly appreciated.

The url I've been using:
http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=constraint&hoursBeforeNow=1&stationString=PAJN&fields=raw_text

An example of the return data:

```
<response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://aviationweather.gov/adds/schema/metar1_2.xsd">
<request_index>59551517</request_index>
<data_source name="metars"/>
<request type="retrieve"/>
<errors/>
<warnings/>
<time_taken_ms>2</time_taken_ms>
<data num_results="1">
<METAR>
<raw_text>
PAJN 080553Z 06006KT 7SM -RA FEW006 FEW024 OVC032 06/04 A2942 RMK AO2 SLP962 P0006 60010 T00560044 10083 20056 51001
</raw_text>
</METAR>
</data>
</response>
```

Airport: Juneau International Airport
lat/long: 58.3586835, -134.5833512
Map Example: [Alaska Airports Google Map](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zWxhQmQil6XU.kkfctwxF-oyk)

I would like to take the "raw_text" and display it below the airport data as METAR data, ideally refreshing the data "on click" or at intervals of x mins. To start I would like to just get Juneau to work, but I would want all the airports to do the same, without having to make a request for 800+ airports each time. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad to answer everything, but let's start with the first bit: fetching the data.

With an XML data source, you can't use AJAX to fetch the data "cross-domain" if the source server doesn't allow your origin, which is the case here as far as I can see.

You have a few solutions though:

1. Have your own server to fetch the data (with PHP for example) and query your own script with AJAX.
2. Check if they provide another feed (JSONP) or a JSON source that allows your origin domain.
3. Find another source for this data.

For your information, Geonames has a webservice for weather / METAR reports. It can be found here: http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html

This can be used with a simple AJAX call. You can open a free account that allows for 30'000 credits daily per application and 2000 credits hourly. Details about credits can be found here: http://www.geonames.org/export/credits.html

Here is a demo query for PAJN: http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?ICAO=PAJN&username=demo

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I appreciate your help. I'll take a good look at it tonight and see what I can come up with.

Comment: What did you come up with then?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JukoJones/p8t6C/1/) is an example of what I was able to come up with. It's pretty basic at the moment. At least I have a starting point. Thank you. I also found that it's pretty difficult to get js to work with google maps. Google earth on the other hand seems to handle it just fine. My next step is to see if I can make that work.